# Is PS3 with Move an alternative to Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii, playstation-move

My girlfriend tried the Wii during holidays and she told me that she liked play Wii Sports game. Now I would prefer to buy the PS3 with Move because I think I can use it more, not only for Move-based games.

Back to my question, is PS3 with Sony Move an alternative to Wii in this case? Which are the differences technically speaking between Sony Move and Wii controllers? Does PS3 game catalog contains sports and music games that support Sony Move?

**More info** (if relevant). The console will be attached to a Samsung (LE40C650) 40" Full HD television. In addition TV is installed in a little dining room with couch placed about 2 meters far from TV.

Comment: Isn't this sort of like asking if Chicken is an alternative to Fish?  Anything is an alternative to anything when compared to everything.

Comment: Could be, but I tried to ask for as much objective facts I could think about. If you have a suggestion how to improve my question is welcome.

Comment: I know this is fairly old, but it just got bumped to the front page so I have to chime in - this makes about as much sense to me as a question asking which console you should buy.  You buy the device **which supports the games you want to play**.  You don't pick a device and then find games.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There will be fewer games that support Move *at the moment* because it's a relatively new device. If you look *today* you might not find the games you want on the PS3, but as time passes more games will be released that make use of Move.

[Digital Trends](http://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/playstation-move-vs-nintendo-wii-under-the-hood/) has an article that compares the Move to a Wiimote. The basic difference is:

> While the accelerometers inside the controller act much as a Wii does, the balls provide what Sony calls a zero point – an absolute location in physical space for the system to peg all the other data to.

While the Wiimote uses its camera to locate the IR emitters in the sensor bar placed above or below the screen, the PS3 uses a camera to locate the glowing ball on the Move. I've never used the Move so I can't tell you whether it's better or worse than the Wii.

Comment: In the Wii, infrared is emitted by the sensor bar and detected by the wiimote. In the Move, infrared is emitted by the controller and detected by the plyastation camera.

Comment: @Raven - isn't that what I said?

Comment: yes, exactly so, after your edit.

Answer (score 5):

Apart the technical part, you also have to keep in mind that Wii is targeted for casual gamers, while the PS3 is more focused on hardcore gamers.

While you will find now or later sports games compatible with the move, it may well be that they will be much harder to approach than their Wii equivalent. You will have much more simulation games in sports than casual games.

My wife also likes playing the Wii as the system is really simple with movement and around 4 buttons to use, while she dislikes the PS3 (we don't have the Move).  It may be different for your girlfriend but keep it in mind and check first the games she could be interested in to see what they propose on the PS3.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a console that you will both enjoy, I would recommend the PS3. The Wii's hardware is rather limited when it comes to 'proper' games. With the PS3 you are getting a much more powerful console (not to mention a blu-ray player).

The Move system is extremely fast and accurate; in my opinion more so than the Wii.

Answer (score 1):

Wii is definitely better for casual gamers who like Wii Sports-like games.

However, it's not nearly as good a choice for serious gamers. The PS3 Move is really brand new, but already has several Wii Sports-like titles out, and as a bonus will in the future probably be supported by other more serious games.

If it was just for her use, I'd recommend Wii, because it's easier to use, and more well-established, but since you wish to use it for serious gaming as well, and also because Move has more potential, I'd recommend the PS3 Move.

Comment: What makes you think the Wii is "completely useless for real gamers"? There are a number of "serious" titles available, some that have multiplayer options too. I'd agree there aren't the numbers of titles and volume of sales that you get for the 360 or PS3.

Comment: I strongly disagree that Wii is 'completely useless for real gamers'. There are many great, first-party games that are not targeted at casual gamers. Wii may lack HD or large numbers of hard core, mature games, but still is quite a viable game console.

Comment: I have re-worded my answer. I'll agree that "completely useless" was perhaps a bit strong. What I meant was that, as a serious gamer, the VAST majority of titles are released only for (a combination of) PC, 360, and PS3. Only the very top titles (such as Guitar Hero, Call of Duty, etc) are generally released for Wii. As a serious gamer, I wouldn't consider the Wii for anything other than its fun casual party/sporty games.

Comment: Major part of 360/PS3 titles are not released on Wii, that's true. However, Wii got its own large collection of decent, quite serious games that are exclusive for Nintendo. Of course, this holds unless one does not count titles such as Super Mario Galaxy or Monster Hunter Tri as serious games :)

Answer (score 1):

I have played Killzone 3 and SOCOM 4, which require calibration on startup. All PS Move games do, that's not the issue. The issue is the fact that, after playing for five minutes, the targeting reticle is slightly off the calibrated result. People on other sites and YouTube videos call this drift.

However when playing games like Goldeneye 007 on the Wii, I notice that I don't get this problem. Even when using the Wii Zapper and actually aiming down its sight.

In general, faster tracking and smoother motion; good for sports games like Virtua Tennis 4, but not so great as I hoped, i.e. don't expect G-Con 45 Namco accuracy like the CRT thing back in the PS1 days (Time Crisis light-gun genre).

All in all, though the graphical upgrade of the PS3 is so great, I won't worry about this issue… unless the Wii-U comes in and allows for light gun games using its sensor bar still.

P.S.: I don't even need to calibrate the Wii.

I think there are other issues such as HDTV setup?
What motion control games you play?

Sports championship and Virtua Tennis are both great, and now there is quite a number. I'd rather play Black Ops using a dual shock, or Goldeneye 007 on the PS Move (coming later) than the Wii, IMO.

Comment: It's likely -- the Wii-U is said to be compatible with all existing wii accessories and controllers.